# Could frying oil seep through food?

Tags: food-safety, oil, frying

Do foods that expand during frying, like many deep-fried delicacies, carry the risk of hot oil infiltrating their inner spaces, possibly leading to mouth burns upon consumption?

Here is what I want to say:

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Have you never eaten a doughnut straight out of the fryer?

Comment: @Tetsujin no I have never ate donut in my entire life but sometime I do taste snacks while my mother is making them. They are not that much hot but they can still retain little bit hot oil as I have asked about.

Answer (score 1):

In a properly cooked, deep fried item, the internal temperature cannot exceed the boiling point of water (100C or 212F), and we are often looking to cook to a lower temperature than that to avoid over cooking.  That is because when you are deep frying, the moisture in the food turns to steam.  Until you get rid of all the moisture you can't get the internal temperature above the boiling point.

How much oil a fried food absorbs depends on the type of food, any coatings or breadings, the temperature of the oil...there are several variables.

People vary in their sensitivity, but you can burn your mouth at about 60C/140F and higher. So there is a risk of burning your mouth whether it is from residual oil that was absorbed in the process or just being hot from cooking.

Comment: The assumption implicit here is that the bulk internal temperature is always relevant. That would almost certainly be true if oil filters through a porous food, but if expansion caused a pocket to open up a passage for oil to flow in, oil entering that wouldn't be cooled on the same way. Of course it would have to not flow out again, and deep fried things are often shaken in a basket to get excess surface oil off, which would encourage flowing back out